# Skip after_commit on destroy in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'd like to skip the `after_commit` callback when `destroy`ing an object, without specifying explicitly a list of methods using the `on` syntax. I.e. something like:

```
after_commit :foo, except: [:destroy]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've found a way to do it on [Ruby Tips](http://brettu.com/rails-ruby-tips-226-after_commit-callback-without-destroy/):

```
after_commit :foo, if: :persisted?
```

or for more complex conditions:

```
after_commit, :foo, if: Proc.new {|record| record.persisted? && [...]}
```

Comment: I'd wonder why you'd prefer this over the more expressive approach of `except: []`?

Comment: @oreoluwa, I'd use it if `:on` had an opposite like `:except`.

Answer (score 13):

In [Rails 6](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/35804) you can use `after_save_commit` as shortcut to `after_commit :foo, on: [:create, :update]`

```
after_save_commit :foo
```

This will skip the callback on destroy.

Answer (score 9):

The shortest solution is the one shared by @dimid , but I believe, right now the pragmatic approach is to list the events you want to handle and just leave out `:destroy`. There are 3 available `:on` options right now, `:create`, `:update` and `:destroy`.

To execute `foo` on create & update:

`after_commit :foo, :on => [:create, :update]`

Alternatively:

`after_commit :foo, on: :create
after_commit :foo, on: :update`

Or since Rails 5 (https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/22516) it's also possible to:

`after_create_commit :foo
after_update_commit :foo`

Comment: For some reason, `destroy!` still called the method using both strategy.